# Is there a way to unload bundle after mach_inject

Tags: macos, mach

I want to load the newer version of bundle to the target process but it's impossible because the bundle with same name already loaded. Changing `CFBundleVersion` or `CFBundleShortVersionString` of bundle doesn't work. The easiest way to do it is simply kill the target process and restart it. But I don't think that it's a best way to do it. So is there another way to do it?

Answer (score 3):

I am facing the same problem with mach_inject. I don't see a straight forward solution without modifying mach_inject.

My solution is to create two bundles. Consider the 1st bundle to be a plugin manager for the real plugin. The plugin manager is very simple and hopefully never needs to be upgraded, it loads and unloads the original bundle with cleanup code added.

I am using Apple's NSBundle class to load and unload the plugin. Before unloading I call the principal class in the original plugin to have it clean up.

Unloading bundles written in objective C is dangerous. 2 & 4 are true in general.

1. Mach_override can not be undone, but can be called in the plugin manager and call code in the real plugin.
2. Categories and protocols are not safe to use in plugins meant to be unloaded.
3. You need to un-swizzle what you swizzled, and remember you can not remove methods, so when you reload the plugin, you need to replace (not add) the old dangling methods. You will need to check your swizzle code.
4. You need to invalidate timers installed, remove observers, and remove anything else added to the run loop.